# I can't install Nvidia GT 635M driver on Lenovo G580

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have purchased recently a new notebook 'Lenovo G580' the problem is simple as it sounds,  i can't install the graphic driver. I tried to install the drivers on the website, none of them worked. 'uncompatible hardware' or simple errors that' they can't continue'.

I tried other drivers, they worked. But after the restart, only GeForce Experience installed no sign of Nvidia Control Panel and in device manager it seems that the driver has a yellow warning sign saying that it couldn't run.

I have no idea what to do next. Is the first time i'm owning this model. Any ideas  ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to do download manually from this nvidia site and run it...
http://www.nvidia.in/Download/Scan.aspx

or else,  to check if the issue is hardware related an External display can be connected to the Laptop to check. If the issue persists performing OSRI (Operating System Re-Install) will confirm if the issue is hardware related.

Hence, please update the drivers from device manager and check if the issue persists before performing the below troubleshooting link...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15048/windows-7-update-driver-hardware-not-working-properly#update-driver-hardware-isnt-working-properly=windows-7

I hope this helps buddy :)

Comment: OP clearly stated they already downloaded the drivers from the website. Please make an effort to make certain your answer addresses the actual problems stated in the question.